# Keep getting unexpected unindent on Python 2.7

Tags: python

I keep getting "unexpected unindent" error on python, i tried everything but i just can't seem to find where i'm making mistakes. Without the while statement the script works, but with the while statement i get the error, here is the part of the code involved

```
import time, requests, json

while True:
    try:
        BU = requests.session() 
        URL = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-PART' 
        r = BU.get(URL, timeout=(15, 10)) 
        MarketPairs = json.loads(r.content) 
        for element in MarketPairs['result']:
            id = element['Id']
            price = element['Price']
            tot = element['Total']
            time = element['TimeStamp']
            type = element['OrderType']
            print type, tot, time, id

except Exception as e:
    print e
    print 'Error... possible timeout'
```

The error is: There is an error in your program: unexpected unindent.

Comment: Please include the actual error message.

Comment: Just edited and included the error

Comment: There is a space before `import` in line 1

Comment: Just made a mistake copying the code here, i checked and on the idle there is no space before import

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message from python. It should indicate where the unexpected indent is. Edit: Maybe IDLE specific?

Comment: I'm shocked -- this question was posed 7 minutes ago and nobody has told OP to stop using IDLE yet? Well I guess it falls to me, then.

Comment: Using IDLE since it was the first option and i'm a noob lol, any better alternative?

Comment: I would say for a better alternative: Use `vi` and call everything command line ;D . But IMO IDLE is just fine for starting out with, it's definitely not the best but I'm certain that you're not doing anything in `python` that is complex enough that you'll really get any benefit out of a better IDE.

Comment: It should highlight which line the unexpected indent.

Comment: You dont have an `except`

Comment: I am flagging this question for closure as the issue was resolved in a way unlikely to be helpful to future readers. Someone with the error of not including an except would be very hard pressed to find this question, recognize it as their own issue as well, and to find the answer to their issue.

Comment: @AdamSmith Sile's programming error has nothing, zero, to do with the editor used.  Telling people what editor to use is as off topic as asking for such opinions.

Comment: @Simon If by 'it', you mean the editor, IDLE does highlight lines with syntax errors.  In this case, the positioning of the highlight is better with recent 3.x than with 2.7.

Comment: @Sile Editor use, like religion is a personal choice.  IDLE is specifically aimed at beginning Python programmers.  It has Python-specific features that you may not find in multi-language editors, which are generally aimed at more experienced users, and lacks some general features that others have.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  Sorry by it I did mean the IDLE

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I didn't think I needed the "/s" tag. Telling new programmers to avoid IDLE is a bit of a meme whose humor springs from the same font as editor wars and spaces vs tabs. I haven't used it in what's likely a decade, but it *used* to be pretty awful even for Python editing, which is why it was originally shunned. I stand by my endorsement to move away from IDLE, if only for the same reason I endorse PEP8 -- if no one else is using it, you shouldn't either. As for being off-topic: it was an off-topic aside posted on an off-topic question as a comment, so it was in good company! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith There have been at least a couple hundred improvements to IDLE in the last decade, some visible to users, some not.   I am interested in knowing what people think are the worst remain defects *today*.  What I find really not funny is people (not you it appears) who suggest to beginners that the solution to writing buggy code is to switch editors.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy agreed, for what it's worth! Buggy code is buggy regardless of the editor used to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full error message should make the problem pretty obvious.

```
File "./test.py", line 17

                                         ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

The line that it is having an error on is one right after the end of the file, so it's expecteing something else.

Every time you have a `try` statement, it needs an `except` statement to know what to do. Your program is expecting that, and since the following line isn't indented equal to the try block, it throws an indentation error because the fact that the line isn't indented is the first thing the program sees and quits.

See [This guide on try/excepts](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm") for more information.

Comment: I tried again and added the Except statement, see my edit, but the error is still the same

Comment: That's because you still have the same issue: The program looks at the next line, sees that it is not indented correctly, and throws the same error. Your `Except` needs to be on the same indentation as the `Try` as all the examples in the link I posted show.

Comment: Ok, problem solved, i did not think about where i was putting that except statement. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to get your answer. Please do note that the proper way to thank someone on Stack Overflow isn't actually by writing "Thank You," but rather by accepting the answer.